# Center Form In Middle of Screen

Tags: html, css

I found this example of a cool effect to center form in middle of screen but for some reason my form appears on the top left of the center box. Anyone know how to get the form to be centered?

CSS is as follows:

```
html {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:#eeeeee;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    background:#fafafa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

I wrapped my form in `<body>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to do like this?

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Centerdive">
  My Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

`HTML`:

```
<body>
    <div class="must-center"></div>
</body>
```

`css`:

```
body{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.must-center{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #f90;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Try it online](https://jsfiddle.net/ef1xcm8y/3/)

Comment: I've updated my answer (fiddle link is added too)   :)

Comment: why downvote?? it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it center of the screen very easily by using margin: 0 auto; and set a width of the form tag. You can try the code below

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background:#fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 96px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
}

form input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Form Center:</h2>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Test input">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Test input 2">
</form>
```